# Enclose paragraphs containing string by text

Tags: unix, awk, latex

I have got a long bibliography file created for use in a .tex file and would like to modify it such that my own citations appear in bold face. This could be manually achieved by enclosing each bibliography item (separated by blank lines) containing my name (let's assume it is Crowe) with \textbf{}.

Is there any way I could automate this process? Maybe using awk? Below is a short example of my original text and the way I'd like it to be modified (note the **\textbf{** preceding the second bib item and the closing **}** at the end).

Thank you for your help!
Robert

```
%---- ORIGINAL FILE ----%

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Aagaard%
\ \BBA {} Andersen%
}{%
Aagaard%
\ \BBA {} Andersen%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {1998}}%
}]{%
Aagaard:1998aa}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
Aagaard:1998aa}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Aagaard, P.%
\BCBT {}\ \BBA {} Andersen, J\BPBI L.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{1998}{Aug}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Correlation between contractile strength and myosin
  heavy chain isoform composition in human skeletal muscle} {Correlation
  between contractile strength and myosin heavy chain isoform composition in
  human skeletal muscle}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Med Sci Sports Exerc}{30}{8}{1217-22}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Young%
, Stokes%
\BCBL {}\ \BBA {} Crowe%
}{%
Young%
\ \protect \BOthers {.}}{%
{\protect \APACyear {1985}}%
}]{%
Young:1985aa}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
Young:1985aa}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Young, A.%
, Stokes, M.%
\BCBL {}\ \BBA {} Crowe, M.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{1985}{Apr}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {The size and strength of the quadriceps muscles of old
  and young men} {The size and strength of the quadriceps muscles of old and
  young men}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Clin Physiol}{5}{2}{145-54}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\end{the bibliography}
```

.

```
%---- MODIFIED FILE ----%

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Aagaard%
\ \BBA {} Andersen%
}{%
Aagaard%
\ \BBA {} Andersen%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {1998}}%
}]{%
Aagaard:1998aa}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
Aagaard:1998aa}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Aagaard, P.%
\BCBT {}\ \BBA {} Andersen, J\BPBI L.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{1998}{Aug}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Correlation between contractile strength and myosin
  heavy chain isoform composition in human skeletal muscle} {Correlation
  between contractile strength and myosin heavy chain isoform composition in
  human skeletal muscle}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Med Sci Sports Exerc}{30}{8}{1217-22}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\textbf{\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Young%
, Stokes%
\BCBL {}\ \BBA {} Crowe%
}{%
Young%
\ \protect \BOthers {.}}{%
{\protect \APACyear {1985}}%
}]{%
Young:1985aa}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
Young:1985aa}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Young, A.%
, Stokes, M.%
\BCBL {}\ \BBA {} Crowe, M.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{1985}{Apr}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {The size and strength of the quadriceps muscles of old
  and young men} {The size and strength of the quadriceps muscles of old and
  young men}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Clin Physiol}{5}{2}{145-54}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}}

\end{the bibliography}
```

Comment: I think it'd be more robust to do this within Latex - http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149743/50142 looks like it might contain some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!  I think you have markup problems but this will do the bold wrapping

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '/bibitem/ && /Crowe/{print "\\textbf{" $0 "}"; next}1' file
```

if there are false positives, you can fine tune pattern matching.

**Explanation**

`-v RS=` sets the paragraph mode, records separated by one or more blank lines

`ORS="\n\n"` normalizes output with a blank line in between records

`/bibitem/ && /Crowe/` if these two patterns found in the record ...

`print "\\textbf{" $0 "}"; next` wrap the current record (`$0`) with prefix and suffix quoted and skip to next record

`1` print the records as is

Comment: Thanks so much, karakfa, this works almost perfectly. The only issue is that this now includes an additional line break preceding each of my publications. Any idea of why that is the case? Also, could you pleas give me a brief explanation of what the above actually does?

Comment: due to ORS, it will only add an extra line at the very end.  There shouldn't be any extra blanks other than between records.  The very last blank line can be deleted by piping to `sed '${/^$/d}'`

Comment: Excellent, many thanks again, karakfa. I'll have to write that down because in the future I most certainly won't be able to reproduce the code. Those additional blank lines preceding the bib items highlighted in bold face might also be a Latex thing. Simply deleting all empty lines in the bibliography file and piping to a new file by

    grep . filename > filename_new
finally gave me the result I wanted.

Comment: please accept this as answer if it satisfies the need and if you think will be useful for others as well.